# React Hook not working in Next.js AMP page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amp-html

Why the following are excluded from amp-rendered pages?

1. React lifecycle methods
2. React callbacks like onClick
3. React Hooks

My Real issue is that if I enable AMP on this page ( Uncomment 3rd line ), router.query.title will not be printed.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import withLayout from 'components/MyLayout';

//export const config = { amp: true };

const Content = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>{router.query.title}</h1>
      <p>This is the blog post content.</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Page = () => (
    <Content />
)

export default withLayout(Page);
```

Answer (score 2):

AMP pages render in server-side only so custom javascript like react lifecycle methods, hooks, react callbacks,... **can't run in client-side**. All javascript process run on the server only and return an HTML output without any react library or custom js bundle file.
To create a dynamic AMP website you should think in the AMP ecosystem and use [its plugin & component](https://amp.dev/documentation/components). To handle state in AMP you can use [amp-bind](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind) compoenent.

Comment: Whooh, was not expecting that ! Thats a big thing. mmm